# How to Run a Continuous Batch Process in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, etl, spark-structured-streaming

I have tried both the spark batch API and spark structured streaming API, but I am still very new to it and wonder how near real-time dimension table can be achieved.

I have a use case for updating a type two dimensional table in near real time(~10min lag). It requires the output of the last job to be the input of the new job. My approach is to run a continuous batch spark job that restarts from the beginning once it finishes all transformation steps, not exits with a success status. It is kind like the streaming job, but runs batches inside and blocking (i.e. no new data are read or processed the last read data are merged into the final dimension table). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Executing everything in a single Spark run is a requirement ? I mean, you want to create a cluster and execute the same data processing sequentially, when one terminates, starts the other ?

Instead you could use an orchestration tool as Apache Airflow that supports executing tasks sequentially, You can take a look at https://airflow.apache.org/code.html and search for "depends_on_past". It'll execute next task only when its predecessor terminates.

Other solution could be a Spark streaming job running with the tumbling windows of 10 minutes and taking the output of your previous task as the input. But ensure that you've enough memory to keep these items during 10 minutes.

======================================

edit:

After reading your comment @Stella I ended up with a new version of my initial proposal. But since I don't know what is your data sources and sinks, I did some elementary version based on a RDBMS (H2) and text files stored locally.

Thus, in the database I added a column storing the version of the rows we want to fetch in each iteration. I also added a column to handle the partitioning (it must be numerical, I wrote a post about here: http://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/partitioning-rdbms-data-spark-sql-jdbc/read).
Now it works as in the following schema:

- Apache Spark Structured Streaming DataFrame reads the first file (starting version) to trigger the job
- later it joins that with the rows in the table marked with given version (Spark SQL, batch)
- at the end it adds new columns to the database with new version to fetch - but it can also update in place

[image]

I wrote a simple illustration code and pushed to my Github: https://github.com/bartosz25/spark-scala-playground/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/waitingforcode/stackoverflow/FeedbackOutputIntoInputSparkTest.scala

The code contains a "simplified" version writing each row in separate query. I'm not sure it'll scale correctly and you should probably prefer batch SQL operations.

Comment: The point of wrapping everything in spark is to avoid airflow queuing system, which becomes a bottleneck for frequently executed jobs, especially when other production jobs are waiting in the same queue.

Comment: @Stella I did some update in the proposition body. Feel free to comment and if you decide to implement, I'm curious how does it perform with your data characteristics (you can send me a PM if you can't tell it publicly).

Comment: This is a very interesting solution and thank you so much for mocking up the code. But if I understand it correctly, it assumes that I can add versions the input file. For my case, I am using Kafka to get new events (create, update, delete), and output the result to s3 and redshift. The next batch uses the s3 stateful result and new kafka events as the input. Am I able to stream kafka events into memory and join it with static s3 data when it becomes ready? How do I manage it when the kafka message exceeds memory size?